# How print array to Xml with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

See that he is bringing the numbers and one in place of "codDedido". I need it to be in xml format .. but I don't know where I'm going wrong.
I populated it like:

```
$listaDados[pedido][listItem][0][codItem]=123;
$listaDados[pedido][listItem][1][codItem]=456;
```

Here my function, :

```
function array_to_xml2($array, &$xml_user_info) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("$key");
                self::array_to_xml2($value, $subnode); 
            }else{
                $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("$key");
                self::array_to_xml2($value, $subnode); 
            }
        }else{
            $xml_user_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
```

here the way I call:

```
foreach ($listaDados['pedido']['listaPedItem'] as $listaD) {
    $teste['listaPedItem'] = $listaD; 
    self::array_to_xml2($teste,$xml_user_info);
    var_dump($listaD);
}
```

So I need that make it:

```
<pedido>
    <listPedItem>
        <codPedido>123</codPedido>
    </listPedItem>
    <listPedItem>
        <codPedido>456</codPedido>
    </listPedItem>
</pedido>
```

But I dont know it returns :

```
<pedido>
   <listPedItem>
    <0>
        <codPedido>
    </0>
    <1>
        <codPedido>
    </1>
  </listPedItem>
</pedido>
```

Comment: what is `$xml_user_info`? Why do you pass the object as an reference? Can you make a stand-alone example (whithout `$this` `self` etc)

Comment: hello @AterLux, tnks for answer.. so in I do:  `$xml_user_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><pedido></pedido>");`  and `self::array_to_xml2($listaDados,$xml_user_info);`

Answer (score -1):

maybe try this function from the official PHP page

```
<?php 
function array2XML($arr,$root) { 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><{$root}></{$root}>"); 
$f = create_function('$f,$c,$a',' 
        foreach($a as $v) { 
            if(isset($v["@text"])) { 
                $ch = $c->addChild($v["@tag"],$v["@text"]); 
            } else { 
                $ch = $c->addChild($v["@tag"]); 
                if(isset($v["@items"])) { 
                    $f($f,$ch,$v["@items"]); 
                } 
            } 
            if(isset($v["@attr"])) { 
                foreach($v["@attr"] as $attr => $val) { 
                    $ch->addAttribute($attr,$val); 
                } 
            } 
        }'); 
$f($f,$xml,$arr); 
return $xml->asXML(); 
} 
?>
```

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php)